# Different domain objects for persistance / forms / validation

Tags: java, hibernate

Imagine you have a domain model consisting of a single class: `Employee`.

You are using Hibernate to persist that model to the database. This means **you will add persistance annotations** like

```
@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue
@Enumerated
```

on your fields.

Then, you decide you want to have a form for the web which you will use to create Employees. This means, **you will expose that model to the web layer** in a view / controller as a form backing model.

Then, you decide you want some validation. Hibernate Validation seems like a good idea and **you will add validation annotations** like

```
@NotNull
@Size
@Min
```

---

Now, for a field like `firstName` in my `Employee` class I now have annotations for different concerns on it and it is used for different uses: **Persistance**, **Web**, **Validation**.

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 14)
@Column
```

On the one hand, I could create a different class for each of the concerns. But that has the downside of having to maintain all those fields. On the other hand I could have one model that has all of those annotations (4+ per field).

Whats best practice here?

Comment: Without knowing the whole picture I'm not sure how useful it would be, but you could think about introducing own annotations grouping certain combinations.

Comment: @Marvin That still has the downside of having annotations for different concerns in the same model class.

Comment: True, that's useful to consider if it's only the amount of annotations that bothers you. Regarding the more general question: I usually feel better with having different classes. This prevents exposing internal details (think about a possible public API later on) and makes the different concerns less dependent on each other (i.e. you can change single parts more easily). However, that's just my opintion.

Comment: @Marvin How do you do the mapping then?

Comment: I have a service that takes one class and returns another. The mapping itself is either based on tedious getter/setter invocations or reflection (Dozer, to be specific).

Comment: I have to agree with @Marvin here. Linking your web layer and data layer is usually not a good idea. You should be able to change your data layer and not have to touch your web layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer) and duplicating the POJOs